# Notation confusion in "On Some Results of Atkin and Lehner" article

Tags: notation, automorphic-forms

I'm currently reading an article on Automorphic Forms, and I'm a bit confused about some of the notation used. The article is "On Some Results of Atkin and Lehner" by William Casselman, published in Mathematiche Annalen, 1973. [Here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/q06948l78345114q/) is a link, but I've attached what I think are the relevant passages below.

In the image below, taken from the second page of the article, in the line that has "Thus we may describe $\varrho(w)$ by specifying for each $f \in \mathcal{G}(k^\times)$ and character $v$ what $(\varrho(w)f)$ **caret-like symbol** $(v,t)$ is", I don't know what the caret-like symbol means. The crazy G, which I denote by $\mathcal{G}$, refers to a space of Schwarz-Bruhat functions.

[image]

And this **caret-like symbol** appears again on the next page (and a few times thereafter).

[image]

Does anyone know what this symbol means?

Comment: $\mathfrak{S}$ - stunning. \mathfrak{S} - it's an S.

Comment: The link to Casselman's paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. It can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF01428197](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01428197).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly suspect it is a familiar notation for the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}\{f\}=\hat{f}$, just put off to the side as if it were an exponent for some reason. (Perhaps using `\widehat`, $\widehat{\varrho(w)f}$, wouldn't have looked so nice, or wasn't available etc.) Of course the usual notion of Fourier transform is generalized when we're talking about locally compact groups in general.

Comment: Oh - this seems to make a lot of sense. Writing math notation was likely far more constricted in 1973 than it is now.

Comment: Yes indeed - it makes complete sense. Thanks for that.